# VTK window in MFC tab control

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, vtk

I have developed a MFC application which contains tabs .I need to link the vtk window inside this tab. How is it possible? I have referred this link " [https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/blob/ee46f867e9bc052f38c3e51534a93aa087af9efd/Examples/GUI/Win32/SampleMFC/vtkMFCRenderView.cpp"](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/blob/ee46f867e9bc052f38c3e51534a93aa087af9efd/Examples/GUI/Win32/SampleMFC/vtkMFCRenderView.cpp%22) but couldn't understand the logic.

Comment: I will guide you step by step, but first, you need to compile that library, VTK, as static library. When you have lib files, you can go in the next step.

Comment: i already compiled vtk

Comment: Good. Then, please compile a console vtk example, for instance, from here: https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/Medical/MedicalDemo4/ this will be necessary in order to take from this test project the include and library files into your MFC project.

Comment: Thanks .I have already done that too.I just need to embed the vtk window into mfc tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your header:

```
#include <vtkMFCWindow.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>
#include <vtkImageActor.h>

class CYourView : public CView
{
...
...
protected:
    vtkMFCWindow* m_pvtkMFCWindow;
    vtkRenderer* m_pvtkRenderer;
    vtkImageActor* m_pvtkImageActor;
...
};
```

in your implementation file (cpp):

```
#include <vtkWin32OpenGLRenderWindow.h>

 CYourView::CYourView()
 {
    // TODO: add construction code here
 
    m_pvtkMFCWindow = NULL;
    m_pvtkRenderer = vtkRenderer::New();
    m_pvtkImageActor = vtkImageActor::New();
 }
 
 CYourView::~CYourView()
 {
    if(NULL != m_pvtkMFCWindow)
        delete m_pvtkMFCWindow;
 }
 
void CYourView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    CYourDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if (!pDoc)
        return;

    // TODO: add draw code for native data here

    if(NULL != m_pvtkMFCWindow && pDC->IsPrinting())
            m_pvtkMFCWindow->DrawDC(pDC);
}

void CYourView::OnInitialUpdate()
{
    CView::OnInitialUpdate();

    // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class

    m_pvtkMFCWindow = new vtkMFCWindow(this);
    m_pvtkMFCWindow->GetRenderWindow()->AddRenderer(m_pvtkRenderer);
    m_pvtkRenderer->SetBackground(0.0, 0.0, 0.5);
    if(NULL != GetDocument()->m_pvtkBMPReader)
    {
        //setup renderer
        m_pvtkImageActor->GetMapper()->SetInputConnection(GetDocument()->m_pReader->GetOutputPort());
        m_pvtkRenderer->AddActor(m_pvtkImageActor);
//      m_pvtkRenderer->ResetCamera();
    }
}

void CYourView::OnDestroy()
{
    if(NULL != m_pvtkRenderer)
        m_pvtkRenderer->Delete();
    if(NULL != m_pvtkImageActor)
        m_pvtkImageActor->Delete();

    CView::OnDestroy();

    // TODO: Add your message handler code here
}

BOOL CYourView::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default

    return TRUE;
//  return CView::OnEraseBkgnd(pDC);
}

void CYourView::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
    CView::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

    // TODO: Add your message handler code here

    if(NULL != m_pvtkMFCWindow)
        m_pvtkMFCWindow->MoveWindow(0, 0, cx, cy);
}
```

this example is for SDI/MDI case, but you easily adapt on CDialog based, if you need it.

**P.S.** In your *stdafx.h* file, you need to insert:

```
#define vtkRenderingCore_AUTOINIT 4(vtkInteractionStyle,vtkRenderingFreeType,vtkRenderingFreeTypeOpenGL,vtkRenderingOpenGL)
#define vtkRenderingVolume_AUTOINIT 1(vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL)
```